# Support request for lack of compatibility of Google Play Services for AR and Samsung Galaxy Tab A7

Tags: arcore

we have bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab A7, model SM-T503, which is listed in the compatible devices for Google Play Services for AR (https://developers.google.com/ar/devices), but when I try to install the package I have a compatibility error. [image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp1zP.jpg)

Google support asked me to reset the device date, clear caches, check for updates, but to no avail.

Tried searching for Google Play Services for AR in Google Play Store and did not find it. Searched for it in the search engine and was redirected to the error page attached above ("Il tuo dispositivo non è compatibile con questa versione" - "your device is not compatible with this version")